# How to render Sprites normally on rotated isometric tiles? LIBGDX

Tags: matrix, libgdx, isometric

i was using this tutorial to make an isometric Map from normal Sprites:
http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2032

I want to render a house on top of my floor tiles at position 0,0, but it looks like this:
http://gyazo.com/c7d5cd74829150c684cfa7b40c9fdfba

Here is my create() and render():

```
@Override
public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    img = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("grass2d.jpg"));

    //House
    house = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("mb_0004.png")));
    house.setSize(2,2);
    house.setPosition(0,0);


    // Camera
    cam = new OrthographicCamera(10,10*(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/(float)Gdx.graphics.getWidth()));
    cam.position.set(5,5,10);
    cam.direction.set(-1,-1,-1);
    cam.near = 1;
    cam.far = 100;
    //Matrices
    //Matrix to rotate floor tiles
    matrix.setToRotation(new Vector3(1,0,0), 90);
    // Subject to change?
    matrix2.setToRotation(new Vector3(0,1,0),45);

    // populate Tiles
    for(int z = 0; z < 100; z++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
            sprites[x][z] = new Sprite(img);
            sprites[x][z].setPosition(x,z);
            sprites[x][z].setSize(1, 1);
        }
    }




    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);

}


@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    cam.update();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    batch.setTransformMatrix(matrix);

    batch.begin();
    for(int z = 0; z < 100; z++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
            sprites[x][z].draw(batch);
        }
    }

    batch.end();
    batch.begin();



    //batch.setTransformMatrix(matrix2);
    house.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
```

I did try to create another Matrix to transform it back, but then my coordinates are messed up. Hope you guys can help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i was able to do it using TiledMap and a self written algorithm to detect wether or not a tile has been clicked and which one. I am able to place my house by mouse now and really like the result.

If anybody is interested, i will take some time to write a small tutorial.

Here is what it looks like at the moment:
[Isometric Tiles](http://gyazo.com/129e1a994a25d5f94665b86d976d1e85)